# Use Azure Ad authentication for payara server login

Tags: azure-active-directory, windows-authentication, payara

I am working on a web application **IUCLID 6** which runs on **payara server**. Both application have username login. I want to use my **azure ad authentication** instead of primitives login for these application. So where should I have to apply this authentication in IUCLID 6 or PAYARA Server and how? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the application in Azure AD, create a Key Vault and store a Key Vault secret, and then configure the Azure secrets on the Payara server. To configure the config source from the admin console, go to Configs > your-config > MicroProfile > Config > Azure Secrets.

[image]

There is a step-by-step guide for this here: https://docs.payara.fish/community/docs/documentation/microprofile/config/cloud/azure.html